# SoftLayer API - Configuration In GUI not available in API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to test an order placement with these configurations:

```
pkgId = 253

prices = [
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'server', 'INTEL_XEON_2650_2_30')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'os',      'OS_UBUNTU_14_04_LTS_TRUSTY_TAHR_64_BIT')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'ram', 'RAM_64_GB_DDR3_1333_REG_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk_controller', 'DISK_CONTROLLER_RAID_1')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'disk0', 'HARD_DRIVE_1_00_TB_SATA_2')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'port_speed', '10_GBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'power_supply', 'REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'bandwidth', 'BANDWIDTH_0_GB')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'pri_ip_addresses', '1_IP_ADDRESS')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'remote_management', 'REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'vpn_management', 'UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'monitoring', 'MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'notification', 'NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'response', 'AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION')},
{'id': getItemPriceId(items, 'vulnerability_scanner',   'NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING')},
```

and I have tried to order it to dallas 10 and paris 1. When I try to verify the order with

```
client['Product_Order'].verifyOrder(productOrder)
```

I get this error:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): The price for Dual Intel Xeon E5-2650 v3 (10 Cores, 2.30 GHz) (#156517) is not valid for location dal10.
```

This doesnt make sense to me, as in the gui for both locations I have the option to order exactly the drive that the API is saying is not valid. Is there something that I am doing wrong here? or is the pricelist for the API outdated?
I have attached a screenshot of the option that I am trying to order that appears in the list for DAL10 but for some reason is impossible to order in the API....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a location conflict for the item price: **156517**, this is not available for **Paris 1** and **Dallas 10** datacenter, to get more information about how item prices works, take a look the following article:

- [Location-based Pricing and
  You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you)

The GUI does some internal processes to get the item price according the location that you will choose, If you would like to order through API, you need to send a standard price (which is valid for all datacenters) or a item price according to the location.